# C++ pointer to array return type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a code like that:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; 

const int ARR_SIZE=5;
int arr[ARR_SIZE];

int (*five(int first))[ARR_SIZE]
{
    int result[ARR_SIZE];
    for (int i=0;i!=5;++i)
    {
        result[i]=(i+first);
    }
    decltype(result) *final_arr=&result;
    return final_arr;
}

template <typename T>
void print_arr(T *beg, T *end)
{
    cout << "[";
    for (;beg!=end;++beg)
        cout << *beg << ", ";
    cout << "]" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    decltype(arr) *a;
    for (int i=1;i!=5;++i)
    {
        a=five(i);
        print_arr(std::begin(*a),std::end(*a));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically I have a function that returns pointer to array and I would like to print the contents of this array. I would expect this code to print four arrays:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]  
[2,3,4,5,6]  
[3,4,5,6,7]  
[4,5,6,7,8]
```

However content of the printed arrays seems random. I would be greatful for a hint on what is wrong with the code.

Comment: It's an amusing juxtaposition to see `decltype` and terrible native C arrays being used badly in the same bit of code.

Comment: @Puppy Though, you have to agree `int (*five(int first))[ARR_SIZE]` is an *interestingly* creative syntax. =)

Comment: Guys I'm trying to learn C++ as a new language coming from Python/F#, i.e. higher level languages. I just though that it might be good to know how to return more low level constructs (like C arrays) for performance reasons. Because what I'm looking for in C++ is performance gain (in scientific computing). So still would be good to know how to return an array from a function.

Answer (score 3):

You are going into undefined behaviour. You return a dangling pointer in `five`.

`int result[ARR_SIZE];` life-time is limited by scope of `five`, therefore it gets freed at the end. Taking its address and returning it does not prolong its life.

This `decltype(result) *final_arr=&result;` effectively doesn't do anything except hiding the error. You could have skipped it and write `return &result;` which would most probably upset compiler seriously enough to not compile the code.

Comment: Thanks. So is there any way to return array from a function? And I mean return array and not simply fill array passed as an argument.

Comment: Return via value, and count on RVO. Otherwise you can only return a dynamically allocated object, then you decide about its life time, for the good and bad.

Answer (score 2):

Your code produces undefined behavior - returning dangling pointer from `five` function - it means you are returning a pointer which points to an object, which is allocated on the stack.